# How bind method works internally for different Service providers in JNDI?

Tags: java, jndi

As per my understanding, in JNDI we are basically bind object with logical names and let the clients access those objects by using that logical name. During binding we do object 
serialization and stored it in the form of bytes so that it can be transferred via network to remote machines.
Does all the service providers implement binding in this manner?
If it is not so then what could be major difference between binding implementation especially in context of service provider. How does binding work for tomcat JNDI service provider i.e. `org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

> During binding we do object serialization and stored it in the form of bytes so that it can be transferred via network to remote machines.

Not necessarily.

> Does all the service providers implement binding in this manner?

No. The Corba COSNaming service is one obvious exception: it binds names to Corba references, whose format is defined by Corba, not by Serialization. The RMI Provider is another: what is serialized in RMI is not the remote object but its stub.

> If it is not so then what could be major difference between binding implementation?

Anything. There is really no limit to what a provider can do.

> How does binding work for tomcat JNDI service provider i.e. org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory.

Another example. This is all in the same process, so there is no serialization at all.